# Velocity engine ( outdated ? )

Tags: velocity

I see there where no updates almost 2 years for the [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) framework ?

Whats going on there ? Is there something new around and that people use?

( I have been using it to render Html mainly )

Comment: Why do you need to change? New version isn't far, we had bug fixes for current version and...anyway...it works pretty well...

Answer (score 3):

There is not so much open issues left open, so it may be released soon. But to paraphrase Adriano comment, 1.7 is working quite well, and contains several important backports from the trunk version.

This said, if you want to benefit from the bleeding edge features, you can give a try to the subversion trunk version (2.0-dev). Here is the [list of main changes](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/changes-report.html#a2.0), among which macro parameters default values and (not yet in the list), a migration towards the Maven build system.

Answer (score 1):

Remember how open source operates.  Development doesn't happen for development's sake.  No one is making money off sales of the latest version.  People improve things as they see need for improvement and have time to make those changes.  Releases happen when there is something worth the effort of putting out a new version.  If it isn't improving, it does not mean that it has been abandoned for something better.  It frequently just means that it is currently "good enough".

This is not the first quiet period Velocity has been through.  And whether it comes out of it or not, you're still asking the wrong question.  All that really matters is whether it does the job you need?  If it has shortcomings, look for alternatives or contribute improvements.  That's how it works.